# How to make groups in firebase authentication using android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have some question about firebase authentication, is possible to make groups? for example i have an app for a salesman and another for a buyer and i want to save authentication in 2 different groups.
I asking this if is possible i can make a firebase automatically do a  difference of tow tipes of credentials.

I'm create a login if password like this;

```
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TagCerta", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        comerciante.setUid(user.getUid());
                        comerciante.salvar();
                        Intent inicio = new Intent(CadastrarActivity.this, ComercianteActivity.class);
                        startActivity(inicio);
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TagErrada", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(CadastrarActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in firebase authentication. To be able to do that, you need to use firebase database, then you can do the following:

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("salesman");
ref.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("name").setValue("peter sells ");

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("buyer");
ref.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("name").setValue("peter buys also! ");
```

Then you would have the following database:

```
salesman
    userId
        name : peter sells 
buyer
   userId
        name : peter buys also!
```